# Somtime, segmentation Inference result is weird in threading with Pytorch

Tags: python, multithreading, pytorch, gpu

I made a program to do semantic segmentation using Pyside.

I have 2 semantic segmentation models.

When i try to inference without threading.

It looks fine.

But when I try to use threading to each model inference, the results are weird

Even though it's the same image, sometimes the value becomes zero or recognizes strange places

Can interference occur in memory and interfere with model inference?

and I actually try this for more frame rate

but i dont know using threading help more inference speed

I tried Queue and torch.cuda.syncronize

Fix image and check input value